What is the easiest way to make a folder accessible only by a user
Create a folder
In security remove authenticated users from owners.
I got this

How to turn off the option for inheriting permissions?
What is "its parent"? A folder containing it?
Why it's so hard?

I've written you an answer with an explanation, but if you have no idea what it all means, you really should not be removing permissions. the chance is too great that you'll lose access. I strongly suggest you to make backups, so you can safely reinstall windows if you do mess up.

What’s your goal, from a security/confidentiality standpoint? Filesystem permissions are easy to circumvent in many common setups.

Technically as an Administrator, you cannot lose access to a file with NTFS, since you can always change the owner as an Administrator.

Warning: Making changes to security settings can cause you to loose access. It can be really hard to restore them. Proceed at your own risk.
Folder security rights propagate from parent folders down to child folders.
If you open This PC, and you click on one of your drives, then that drive is the parent of your folder structure.
Lets say, you open C:, the parent folder is C:\ and all folders under it are its children.
Lets say, you now open C:\Temp (assuming it exists), C:\Temp is a child of C:, but if C:\Temp has children of its own, then C:\Temp is the parent for those children.
By default, security permissions for a folder is always set to inherit the permissions from the folder above it (its parent).
While you can still add permissions to a child, you cannot change existing ones unless you disable inheritance.
Removing a usergroup as you tried in your question cannot be done because that usergroup is also on the parent folder.
To remove Users, first go to advanced permissions, and at the bottom untick inherit permissions.
Press Apply and copy the permissions back. If you now press OK, and come back to the previous permissions, you'll see that all the light-gray checkboxes are now normal ones, and you can now fully make changes.
Do note, removing permissions can cause you to remove your own access.
Even though the Users group may seem like its not you, your user is inside it, so unless you also add your own user back, removing the Users group will cause you to lose access yourself.
Given you want to restrict a folder to a single user, if that user is not you, do note that you will effectively lose access to that folder after the change, and only that user can restore it.
